# Recover NTFS partition back without formatting

Tags: hard-drive, external-hard-drive, ntfs, partition-recovery

If I try to chkdsk, I get the error

```
Unable to unable to determine volume version and state
```

I'm currently running a Partition Wizard Home Edition scan on the drive and it is
finding files and directories so I'm optimistic that most of the data is
still intact, but I wonder if it's possible to simply rebuild the NTFS
structure on-disk and not have to go through the hoop of copying the data to
another drive.

I went through the answers to similar questions, but most of them have solutions like

1. Recover the data and format it
2. Use chkdsk
3. Use some propietory software, I tried a large number of softwares and 100% of them ONLY helped in recovering the data, I want to re-build the NTFS structure of the partition without formatting that partition.

FYI - Other partitions on that disk are working fine.

Comment: Is the affected partition still accessible from OS or has it disappeared?

Comment: This is a horrible idea.  Recovering the data to another drive and verifying that it was successful is the best way to go.  I know of tons of programs to extract the data, but none that can undo the damage by themselves.  What if the software only partially fixes the file system, now you have a landmine out there just waiting to blow up in your face.  How will you know the file system has truly been repaired?

Comment: @cybernard various software utilities are successfully reading the NTFS on the affected partition. It's just windows which is unable to read it, and hence I need something like that.

Comment: RStudio, PhotoRec, and other will recover the data to another hard drive.  Data recovery software is designed NOT to write on the disk to be recovered so to avoid damaging good data accidentally.  It forces the user to copy the data to another hard drive, format it, and copy it back so there is 0% chance the recovery software damages the hard drive to be recovered.  In linux part of the ntfsprogs package there is ntfsfix, but I have never used it so I don't know how good it is.